# Make KSoap2 android work with ReliableSession (WS-ReliableMessaging)

Tags: java, android, wcf, web-services, android-ksoap2

I try to connect my android app to my web service.
The android use ksoap2-android as library and my web service is a .NET WCF.

My WebService configuration:

```
<wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpBindingConfiguration" useDefaultWebProxy="false" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" receiveTimeout="00:40:00" openTimeout="00:40:00" closeTimeout="00:40:00" sendTimeout="00:40:00">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        <security mode="None" />
        <reliableSession inactivityTimeout="24:00:00" enabled="true" />
    </binding>
</wsHttpBinding>
```

This is my android code:

```
final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/IService1/Register";
final String METHOD_NAME = "Register";
final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
final String URL = "http://10.0.0.1:6474/Server";

SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

Element e = new Element();
e.setName("To");
e.setNamespace("http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing");
e.addChild(Node.TEXT, URL);


Element e1 = new Element();
e1.setName("Action");
e1.setNamespace("http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing");
e1.addChild(Node.TEXT, SOAP_ACTION);

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
        SoapEnvelope.VER12);

PropertyInfo info = null;
info = new PropertyInfo();
info.namespace="http://tempuri.org/";
info.name="eventObjectUri";
info.type=PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
info.setValue("Qing");
request.addProperty(info);

envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
envelope.headerOut = new Element[] { e, e1 };


androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
```

The `getResponse()` throw :
`Code: s:Sender, Reason: The action http://tempuri.org/IService1/Register is not supported by this endpoint. Only WS-ReliableMessaging February 2005 messages are processed by this endpoint.`
If I disable `reliableSession` my code work, but I need it enable for my project :(

There is someone who found a way to make ksoap2-android work with `reliableSession` ? or ksoap2 is not able to do it ?

**EDIT:**
After using wireshark, I saw that the webService is waiting another command to initiate the the session before being able to use normal command that containe uid session.
I think it is more easy to rewrite my own reliableSession that try to emulate with java/ksoap2-android the "WS-ReliableMessaging".

Comment: I am having the same problem. Any luck, please share